# How to preemptively mock a class that gets instantiated by another class

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I suspect the "best" answer to my question is to use dependency injection and avoid the issue entirely. Unfortunately I don't have that option...

I need to write a test for a class which causes a third party library to be instantiated. I want to mock/stub the library class so that it doesn't make live API calls.

I'm using phpunit in the CakePHP v3.x framework. I'm able to mock the library and created stub responses, but this doesn't prevent the "real" class from being instantiated by code outside of my test. I considered trying to mock the class(s) upstream from the instantiation, but there are a *lot* of them, which would make the test incredibly unwieldy to write/maintain.

Is there a way to somehow "stub" the instantiation of the class? Similar to the way we can tell php unit to expect an API call and preset the returned data?

Comment: You state you can't have dependencies injected, but can you replace the "new" statement for a Factory invocation? This way you could take control over the Factory and make ir return the mock.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHPUnit you are able to get a mock of the API class. Then you can specify how it will interact with what methods and arguments are used.

Here is an example from phpunit.de site (chapter 9):

```
public function testObserversAreUpdated()
{
    // Create a mock for the Observer class,
    // only mock the update() method.
    $observer = $this->getMockBuilder('Observer')
                     ->setMethods(array('update'))
                     ->getMock();

    // Set up the expectation for the update() method
    // to be called only once and with the string 'something'
    // as its parameter.
    $observer->expects($this->once())
             ->method('update')
             ->with($this->equalTo('something'));

    // Create a Subject object and attach the mocked
    // Observer object to it.
    $subject = new Subject('My subject');
    $subject->attach($observer);

    // Call the doSomething() method on the $subject object
    // which we expect to call the mocked Observer object's
    // update() method with the string 'something'.
    $subject->doSomething();
}
```

If the API returns something then you can add will() to second statement as follows:

```
   ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));
```

Comment: The class in question is much further upstream than just 1 level. So, even if it would work, it would be like 15 of these types of things. Unless I'm misunderstanding things here.

Comment: Is there any way you can create a class alias so that anything that instantiates the real class will actuality create your mock class?

Comment: If you use "->will($this->returnValue($someVariable))" then you're basically expecting that update() will return $someVariable. update() itself however won't be invoked. So you won't need to go past 1st level.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can mock instantiation because 'new' is a language construct, and there is no way to mock native functionality. There are few options to consider, one worth than other:

- mock 3rd party API
- wrap the library with own proxy/decorator
- mock the whole library and replace it in composer for testing